# Is it possible to maximum occurences of a value for each key in my table all in one query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Here is the query I'm running to get the counts of each value, for each key of a given object:

```
SELECT key, value, COUNT(value)
FROM keyval kv
WHERE object_id = 123456
GROUP BY kv.key, kv.value
ORDER BY kv.key, kv.value;
```

The table I'm querying off of is very simple. It's just:

```
object_id BIGINT
key       VARCHAR(45)
value     VARCHAR(45)
```

So I get values like:

```
Color    Red     26
Color    Blue    24
Shape    Circle  14
Shape    Square  12
```

So I want to parse out the results for Blue and Square, but keep the results for Red and Circle. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to only get the two key/value with most occurences=

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I want.

Comment: I woudl start by not ever using a key value store for data like this.

Comment: @HLGEM *multi key value

Comment: I misunderstood you @JimmyT., I thought you meant two as in key and value, not key/value key/value. No, there will be at least 8 keys (could be unlimited) with unlimited values, and I need to get the value with the most occurrences for that key.

Comment: I also hate when people submit close votes without actually giving input so I can make the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this but beware the situation where red and blue both have count of 26... both will be returned.

```
with cte as
    (select k,v,count(v) c
    from #kvp
    group by k,v)
select results.* 
from 
    cte restults
    inner join (select k, max(c) m from cte group by k) filter
        on restults.k = filter.k
where 
    filter.m = restults.c
    and id = @id
```

Comment: sorry just noticed the MySQL tag... above is for sql server but you can probably use the logic and just modify the code

Comment: Shoot, I just noticed the tags... Sorry, I didn't mean to tag my question as MySQL. This is actually for Amazon Redshift which is run on PostgreSQL.

Comment: @NobleUplift - that syntax is still valid for PostgreSQL

Comment: It works! Thanks for the warning, because it turns out I actually have two values at 22! I just chose one randomly; what matters is the numeric counts. This was a lifesaver at work, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use row_number in a subquery or a cte:

```
select
    [key],
    value,
    cnt
from (
     select
         [key],
         value,
         count(*) as cnt,
         row_number() over(partition by [key] order by count(*) desc) rnk
     from keyval
     where object_id = 123456
     group by
         [key],
         value
     ) kv
where rnk = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d869/5

Comment: What's a cte? And could you explain how this works? I checked your SQL Fiddle on January 5th and it was already down.

Comment: A CTE is a Common Table Expression. Here is more info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Oh derp, I've been using CTEs this whole time, I just didn't know they had a name (referred to them by keyword). Though this is a good solution, Redshift uses Postgres 8.0, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT KEY,
       value,
       Max(cnt)
FROM  (SELECT KEY,value,Count(value) As cnt
       FROM   keyval kv
       WHERE  object_id = 123456
       GROUP  BY kv.KEY,kv.value
       ORDER  BY kv.KEY Desc,kv.value Desc
       ) a
GROUP  BY a.KEY
```

Comment: This just returns all my keys and values as they show up for the inner query.